# In how many combination can I deal 6 cards with only 2 numbers on them

Tags: combinatorics

I'm struggling to find the correct number of combinations for the following question:

Suppose you have a standard deck of 52 cards. For the sake of simplicity, we'll assume that there are $4$ distinct type of cards, and every $13$ cards of each type are numbered from 1 to 13. How many combination can I deal $6$ cards of all $52$ cards, such that from all the cards I've dealt, there are only $2$ numbers on them.

For example: Those are possible combinations: $\{1,1,1,1,2,2\}$, $\{1,3,1,1,3,3\}$.

I know the the sum of all possible combination of choosing 2 distinct numbers from a set : $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13\}$ is $\binom{13}{2}$. However, I'm not quite certain on how to follow this.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you want to do is determine which value appears twice. There are $13$ values, and we want only one to repeat twice. So we select this value in $\binom{13}{1}$ ways. Now each value appears four times, one for each suit. So we select two suits in $\binom{4}{2}$ ways.

Finally, we select our remaining four values in $\binom{12}{4}$ ways. There are $4$ ways to select the suit for each value, so we multiply by $4^{4}$.

Each of these selections are independent. So by the rule of product, we multiply to obtain:
$$\binom{13}{1} \binom{4}{2} \binom{12}{4} 4^{4}$$

Possible hands.

**Edit:** Based on your revised question, we select our two numbers in $\binom{13}{2}$ ways. This leaves $8$ total cards; of which, we select $6$ in $\binom{8}{6}$ ways. These selections are independent. So by rule of product, we multiply:

$$\binom{13}{2} \binom{8}{6}$$

Comment: Hey, thanks for commenting! I've edited the question because I understood from you answer that I phrased it incorrectly. Take a look at the edited question.

Comment: @0rka Check out my edit!

Comment: OH! I get it now! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> One deck of 52 cards, count all six-card combinations that have only two ranks.

Counting (AAAABB) : Choose the first rank (13), choose the second rank (12). One possibility for the AAAA (no choice), choose 2 B cards out of 4.

> (AAAABB) : $13*12*{4 \choose 2}$

Counting (AAABBB) : Choose two ranks out of 13, choose 3 A cards out of 4, choose 3 B cards out of 4.

> (AAABBB) : ${13 \choose 2}*{4 \choose 3}^2$

What you want is the sum of these two numbers (check that you know how to compute them).

> Bonus : compare this to the total number of 6-card combinations, which is ${52 \choose 6}$. Yeah, most of the time, a 6-card combination does not have two ranks, exactly.

**Hope this helps!**